# Trouble creating a for loop that calls function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'm very new to programming, and most of my experience is in python, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around my schools subject matter. I have to write a function that plays the 99 bottles of beer song, and then call the function in a for/while loop. Here is the code I have so far:

```
function annoyingSong(bottles){
  console.log(bottles +" bottles of soda on the wall, "+ bottles +" bottles of soda, take one down pass it around " + (bottles-1) +" bottles of soda on the wall")
  return bottles +" bottles of soda on the wall, "+ bottles +" bottles of soda, take one down pass it around " + (bottles-1) +" bottles of soda on the wall";
}

for (let i = annoyingSong(); i <= 1; i--){
  annoyingSong(5)
}
```

The goal is to have the loop OUTSIDE the function, (while, in my mind it would make more sense for it to be IN the function) and still incrementing down. When declaring the function I used "bottles" as the parameter.

Comment: What do you think the value of `i` is? And what do you think happens when you call `annoyingSong(5)`?

Comment: The way you wrote it has the loop outside the function, it just needs some adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

`for (let i = annoyingSong(); i <= 1; i--){` initializes `i` to be a string, since the function `annoyingSong` returns a string.

What you want is to call the function with the number of bottles starting from 99 to 1.

So, a for loop starting from i = 99 until i = 0 while decrementing i by one every time.

Here is how it would look like

```js
function annoyingSong(bottles){
  console.log(bottles +" bottles of soda on the wall, "+ bottles +" bottles of soda, take one down pass it around " + (bottles-1) +" bottles of soda on the wall")
  // No need to return because it just prints a value
}

for (let i = 99; i > 0; i--){
  annoyingSong(i) // Call annoying song 99 times, each time with i decrementing
}
```

Comment: That makes total sense- Thank you for that!

Comment: Glad it helped! Please mark my answer as correct if you don't have any further questions.